# Swift : Override method drawInContext of CALayer not beeing called after setNeedsDisplay

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

The control as 3 custom layers and is something like this:

```
class BASwitch: UIControl {
    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)
         ...
         self.toggleLayer = BASwitchToggleLayer()
         self.layer.addSublayer(self.toggleLayer)
         self.toggleLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
         ...
    }
}
```

When the `toggleLayer` is changed inside an selector invoked from `UIViewControl` the  `drawInContext` is called and the content of `toggleLayer` is updated.

**When the `toggleLayer` is invoked from inside an render `delegate` method (renderer from `SCNSceneRendererDelegate`) the `drawInContext` method is not called.**

In both situations the update to the layer is perform in the same way by this code:

```
self.toggleLayer.offString = newValue
self.toggleLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Have Swift something like `doEvents()` of `C# windows` forms that needs to be called?
Can't figure out if is this the problem or any other way to force the update.

Comment: Stepping back, i found the problem is not the custom control itself. An update to simple control label from inside the renderer method is not displayed too.